# What does the "it" replace in this passage from a Murakami short story?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

I would like some help with what the word *it* in the paragraph below (with emphasis added; the word is not emphasized in this way in the original). Does *it* refer to the TV or the antenna outlet?

The passage is taken from Haruki Murakami's *TV People*.

> Everything gets removed from the sideboard to make room for the television. The TV people plug it into a wall socket, then switch it on. Then there is a tinkling noise, and the screen lights up. A moment later, the picture floats into view. They change the channels by remote control. But all the channels are blank---probably, I think, because they haven't connected the set to an antenna. There has to be antenna outlet somewhere in the apartment. I seem to remember the superintendent telling us where it was when we moved into this condominium. All you had to do was connect **it**. But I can't remember where it is. We don't own a television, so I've completely forgotten.

Comment: Could be either. It is a moot point as to whether a TV is connected to an aerial or an aerial to a TV. It might have been better had the author said *All you had to do was to connect them*.

Answer (score 1):

> There has to be antenna outlet somewhere in the apartment. I seem to remember the superintendent telling us where it was when we moved into this condominium. All you had to do was connect IT. But I can't remember where it is. We don't own a television, so I've completely forgotten.

This is an apartment building and somewhere in the building (presumably on the roof), there is an big central antenna and coaxial cables run from the antenna to each apartment.  In each apartment is an "outlet" that looks like [this](http://www.dumoresupplies.com/images/08-61067%20Coaxial%20Cable%20Plate.jpg).  What you need to do to make the TV work is run a cable from the back of the TV to the plug on the outlet.

In the sentence "You have to connect it", the exact antecedent for *it* is ambiguous -- "You have to connect it, the TV, to the wall", "You have to connect it, the the plug on the wall, to the TV", or "You have to connect it, the system, all together" -- but as WS2 points out, the overall meaning is clear.